# OOP-Inheritance: $this in subclass Y (which inherits from X) is pointing to X when method from Y called from X

Tags: php, oop, object, inheritance, parent

I have huge project and in some point of extending it I want to do something `$this` in subclass `Y` (which inherits from `X`) pointing to `X` when method from `Y` called from `X` :) I can't interfere to much in class structure and I want to do it NICELY without any "helpers", additional constructor parameters with "controller path" or something like that.

So the problem is: when I instantiate `ControllerGallery` it calls constructor which calls parent contructor (from `ControllerResource` which is parent of `ControllerGallery`). But in parent constructor (`ControllerResource`), variable `$this` is pointing to `ControllerGallery`, not `ControllerResource`.

I know that when I instantiate class, there is only one object which is created (only "`ControllerGallery`", not: "`ControllerGallery` and it's parent `ControllerResource`"), and that's the problem. My question is: how to achieve the result which is shown below? Any suggestions?

```
<?php

abstract class Controller {
    function getParentController()
    {
        return null;
    }

    function getController(){
        return $this;
    }
}

class ControllerResource extends Controller
{
    protected $CONTROLLER_PATH = 'Resource';
    protected $scripts;

    function __construct(){
        $this->addScript($this->CONTROLLER_PATH.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'general_resource_support_script.js');
    }

    function addScript($name){
        $this->scripts[] = $name;
    }

    function getParentController()
    {
        return parent::getController();
    }

    function getScriptPaths(){
        return $this->scripts;
    }
}

class ControllerProduct extends ControllerResource
{
    protected $CONTROLLER_PATH = 'Product';
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->addScript($this->CONTROLLER_PATH.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'product_support_scripts.js');
    }
}

class ControllerGallery extends ControllerResource
{
    protected $CONTROLLER_PATH = 'Gallery';
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->addScript($this->CONTROLLER_PATH.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'gallery_scripts.js');
    }
}



$controllerProduct = new ControllerProduct();
$controllerGallery = new ControllerGallery();

echo('<pre>');
print_r($controllerProduct->getScriptPaths());
print_r($controllerGallery->getScriptPaths());
echo('</pre>');

echo('
<pre>
<b>SHOULD BE:</b>
Array
(
    [0] => <b>Resource</b>\general_resource_support_script.js
    [1] => Product\product_support_scripts.js
)
Array
(
    [0] => <b>Resource</b>\general_resource_support_script.js
    [1] => Gallery\gallery_scripts.js
)
</pre>
');


?>
```

And we get the result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Product\general_resource_support_script.js
    [1] => Product\product_support_scripts.js
)
Array
(
    [0] => Gallery\general_resource_support_script.js
    [1] => Gallery\gallery_scripts.js
)
```

But it should be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Resource\general_resource_support_script.js
    [1] => Product\product_support_scripts.js
)
Array
(
    [0] => Resource\general_resource_support_script.js
    [1] => Gallery\gallery_scripts.js
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`protected $CONTROLLER_PATH` is declared in both, `ControllerResource` and `ControllerProduct` classes. In PHP you can redeclare public and protected method, but since `ControllerProduct extends ControllerResource` value of that variable will be the value in derived class. If you change the visibility of `$CONTROLLER_PATH` property to private it will belong to that class only and will not be overridden.

[PHP Visibility](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php)

Comment: No... I must had some eclipse of mind. Very strange. Maybe i'm overworked. THANK YOU VERY, VERY MUCH! Of course it works.